# How To keep existing record with new one in android database

Tags: android

I want to update the record,But I want to keep the old record too.For example if I have a record name="a" then I want to update the name with "b" but also I want to keep the old name="a".In simple I want to keep name="a" and also "b"

Comment: what do you actually mean!!

Comment: Is the name the primary key? Do you need to differentiate between old records and new? Perhaps update the question with table layout and more specific examples of what you want to achieve.

Comment: This question is too localize and hard to answer without sample codes nor a some sort of usecase.

Comment: Do you want to append the new data in the old one?

Answer (score 0):

I thing you need to maintain an another log-table. for each update transaction in the table you need to move the copy of old record to log-table. Don't forget to remove the primary key in log-table. I will keep all the records will same primary key.

Comment: You mean to make another table for the porpuse to update the record only.Not insertion operation to perform

Answer (score 0):

Keep a flag. Add a column named `isValid` contain boolean value. When you are inserting a new record with name "a", make that record's `isValid` to `true`. Whenever you are updating name of "a" to "b", insert that record "b" with `isValid` value `true` and make record "a"'s `isValid` flag to `false`.

Thus you can take valid new information by taking records with `isValid` value `true` by using a `WHERE` condition, while keeping the old records. Hope this helps.

Comment: can explain with example please

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this.

```
UPDATE tableName SET columnName=CONCAT(oldValue, ', newValue') WHERE conditionColumn=coulmnValue;
```

**Note:**
It is not good practice.You better to create another alias table for  keeping existing data safe use.

Comment: Is this correct: db.update(TABLE_SECOND_NAME,cv,"COL_SECOND_2=CONCAT(COL_SECOND_2, ', COL_SECOND_2') WHERE ROLL=?",new String[]{roll});